# Solve $\dot v + \frac{\alpha}{m}v + \frac{\beta}{m} v^2 = g$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\alpha, \beta$ are constants.

I know this is a Riccati equation, and I've tried to find a particular solution, with no success.

Also, $v = v(t)$, but $t$ is not part of the equation explicitly, so maybe that could help somehow?

I don't know what else to try, I'd appreciate a push in the right direction.

Comment: Are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ constants or functions?

Comment: constants, i'll clarify this in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look for a constant function $v=km$ with $k$ an arbitrary constant.

Then $\dot v=0$ and $\dot v + \dfrac{\alpha}{m}v + \dfrac{\beta}{m} v^2 = g\Rightarrow\alpha k+\beta mk^2=g\Rightarrow\beta mk^2+\alpha k-g=0\Rightarrow k=\dfrac{-\alpha\pm\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\beta mg}}{2\beta m}$.

So we have to distinct particular solutions: $v=\dfrac{-\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\beta mg}}{2\beta m}$ and $v=\dfrac{-\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\beta mg}}{2\beta m}$.

I'd recommend to rename that little monster and work with an additional constant ($km$ itself if you want) to solve the general case.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. Though I think you meant $v = km$.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Darsen is of course correct for the case where $\dot v =0 \; .$ That being said, my first observation is that this equation is integrable. Observe that $$\dot v  = g - \frac{\alpha}{m}v - \frac{\beta}{m} v^2$$

$$\text{implies}$$

$$\frac{\dot v}{g - \frac{\alpha}{m}v - \frac{\beta}{m} v^2}  = 1 $$

whenever $\dot v \neq 0$ thus we can find an expression for $v$ using

$$\int\frac{dv}{g - \frac{\alpha}{m}v - \frac{\beta}{m} v^2}  = \int dt \; .$$

Use some good integral tables and you will find a solution where $v$ is easy to isolate. Let me know if you need any more guidance.

Edit:

pujfei is also correct in his answer and you'll find that the integral above is a flavor of the $\arctan $ function.

Answer (score 1):

If you know it is a Riccati equation $y'+ay^2=...$, but do not know a particular solution, you can also use the parametrization $y=\frac{u'}{au}$. Here that results in
$$
y=\frac{mu'}{βu}\implies mu''+αu'-gβu=0
$$
which is a linear DE of second order with constant coefficients that can be solved with standard methods.

Answer (score -3):

## Result

Given the original equation:

$$
v'(t)+\frac{\alpha  }{m}v(t)+\frac{ \beta }{m}v(t)^2=g
$$

The general solution is:

\begin{equation}
v(t)= \frac{-\alpha +\sqrt{-\alpha ^2-4 \beta  g m} \tan \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{t \sqrt{-\alpha ^2-4 \beta  g m}}{m}-c_1 \sqrt{-\alpha ^2-4 \beta  g m}\right)\right)}{2 \beta }
\end{equation}

Or:

$$
\begin{align*}
v(t)&=\frac{-\alpha+\sqrt{-\alpha^2-4bgm}\tan{\big[\frac{1}{2}\big(-\frac{\sqrt{-\alpha^2-4{\beta}gm}}{m}{\cdot}t-\sqrt{-\alpha^2-4{\beta}gm}{\cdot}c_1\big)\big]}}{2{\beta}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2{\beta}}\bigg(-\alpha+\sqrt{-\alpha^2-4{\beta}gm}\tan{\big[\frac{1}{2}\big(-c_1\sqrt{-\alpha^2-4{\beta}gm}-\frac{\sqrt{-\alpha^2-4{\beta}gm}}{m}{\cdot}t\big)\big]}\bigg)\\
&=\frac{1}{2{\beta}}\bigg(-\alpha+\sqrt{\Delta}\tan{\big[\frac{1}{2}\big(-c_1\sqrt{\Delta}-\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{m}{\cdot}t\big)\big]}\bigg)
\end{align*}
$$

In which the discriminant for this kind of differential equations is apparently:

$$
\Delta=-\alpha^2-4{\beta}gm
$$

## Proof

The solution is achieved by applying the following transformation to a general form of Riccati Equation.

A Riccati Equation is an equation that looks like this:

$$y'(x)=q_0(x)+q_1(x)y(x)+q_2(x)y^2(x),q_2(x)\neq0\tag{1}$$

It can always be reduced to a second order linear ordinary differential equation (**ODE**).

With:

$$y'=q_0(x)+q_1(x)y+q_2(x)y^2\tag{2}$$

Let $v=yq_2$, we'll have:

$$v'=v^2+R(x)v+S(x)\tag{3}$$

where
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
S&=q_0q_2\\
R&=q_1+\frac{q^{'}_2}{q_2}
\end{align}\tag{4}
\right.
$$

To continue, substitute:

$$v=-\frac{u'}{u}\tag{5}$$

We'll achieve a linear 2nd order **ODE**:

$$u''-Ru'+Su=0\tag{6}$$

Whose general solution is:

$$
\begin{equation}
u(x)= c_1 e^{\frac{1}{2} x \left(R-\sqrt{R^2-4 S}\right)}+c_2 e^{\frac{1}{2} x \left(R+\sqrt{R^2-4 S}\right)}
\end{equation}\tag{7}
$$

Thus we have:

$$
\begin{align}
y&=-\frac{u'}{q_2u}\\
&=\frac{1}{2q_2}\left(-R+\sqrt{R^2-4 S} \left(-1+\frac{2 c_1}{c_2 e^{x \sqrt{R^2-4 S}}+c_1}\right)\right)
\end{align}\tag{8}
$$

For the instance in this question:

$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
q_0&=g\\
q_1&=-\frac{\alpha}{m}\\
q_2&=-\frac{\beta}{m}\\
R&=q_1=-\frac{\alpha}{m}\\
S&=q_2q_0=-\frac{g\beta}{m}\\
R^2-4S&=\frac{\alpha^2+4{\beta}mg}{m^2}
\end{align}\tag{9}
\right.
$$